# Android - Socket connect well but crash just after connection

Tags: android, android-studio, sockets

I try to create a very simple socket connection between the Android app I'm developing and a python server on my VPS.

The connection work well (I see the connection on the server side), but just after the connection is made the app crash. The error is :

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2

```
Process: com.example.socket_test, PID: 5757

java.net.SocketException: already connected

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:601)

    at com.example.socket_test.MainActivity$test$test$1.run(MainActivity.kt:33)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Do you understand/know why ???

Here is my code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Button_Connecter.setOnClickListener {
        test()
    }

}

private fun test() {

    var test = Thread{
        var socketAddress: SocketAddress = InetSocketAddress("XX.XX.XXX.XXXX", 65535)

        var s = Socket("XXX.XX.XX.XX", 65535)

        s.connect(socketAddress, 65535)

    }

    test.start()


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hum, the answer was easy... As written in my code I try to connect several times that's why the app crashed !

The connection can be created in only one line : var s = Socket("XXX.XX.XX.XX", 65535)